# how to explicitly state the start/end of a string

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've been working with some code that opens a workbook and finds values based off a reference cell. It searches for a string and takes the cell next to it. unfortunately i now have 2 cells in the workbook that 'contain' the reference string. one cells is "Current Score" the other is "Percentage of Current Score". Is there a way to state that I just want "Current Score" and nothing else in the cell.

Sorry if this is a tad wordy, I can provide the code if necessary

**EDIT:** Here is the code:

```
Sub Future_Score()

    Dim r
    Dim findValues() As String
    Dim Wrbk As Workbook
    Dim This As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i
    Dim tmp
    Dim counter
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress
    Dim rng As Range

    ReDim findValues(1 To 3)
    findValues(1) = "Curren" & "*" & "Core"
    findValues(2) = "dummyvariable1"
    findValues(3) = "dummyvariable2"


    counter = 0

    r = Range("A163").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(163, 1), Cells(r, 1))
    Set This = ThisWorkbook

    For Each tmp In rng
        Workbooks.Open tmp
        Set Wrbk = ActiveWorkbook
        'For Each sht In Wrbk.Worksheets
        Set sht = ActiveSheet
            For i = 1 To 3
                With sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
                Set c = .Find(findValues(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        secondAddress = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
                        thirdAddress = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
                        Do
                            This.Activate

                            tmp.Offset(0, 4).Value = firstAddress

                            Set c = .FindNext(c)
                            counter = counter + 1
                        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Value = firstAddress
                    End If
                End With
            Wrbk.Activate
            Next
        'Wrbk.Activate
        'Next sht
        Wrbk.Close
    Next tmp
End Sub
```

Have played around with the code a bit. The dummy variables will be in use for other functions, but basically the gist is to open a workbook, find a cell, take the cell next to it, paste in the original workbook. The problem is it picks up multiple cells that contain a string. I have used `"Curren" & "Core"` as the macro doesn't seem to handle spaces in strings to well.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown the code that you are using, but why not just check the cell's value for the exact string "Current Score" and not check the cell to see if it contains that string? PS - always provide relevant code when asking questions about code.

Comment: Updated :) I have never specified to search 'only' and not 'containing', how would I do this? I thought the limits on the string were inherent?

Comment: Actually, you have with the .Find() method call, it looks into the value to see if it can find it anywhere in the value. This is not the same as checking the value to see if it is exactly equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`Set c = .Find(findValues(i), LookIn:=xlValues)`

to

`Set c = .Find(findValues(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

to require that the *entire cell* match the search string, rather than just part of the cell.

Comment: Ah, that was a simple change haha :) Thanks so much for the help, was really baffling me that one!!